# When i add forward slash after blog then it's not working

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on   # Turn on the rewriting engine
    RewriteRule ^blog-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ blog_detail.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

Basically I want URL Something Like  - http://www.hostname.org/blog/anything

But now show - http://www.hostname.org/blog-anything (It's work properly)

Please help!

Comment: So you want to change your 'dash' to a 'slash'... `RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ blog_detail.php?id=$1`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog-([\w-]+)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/([\w-]+)/?$ /blog_detail.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```